# How to change affiliation number font?

Tags: affiliation

I cannot change the font size of the first affiliation (#1)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[justification=raggedright]{caption}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subfig}
\UseRawInputEncoding
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[font=bf,labelsep=space]{caption}

%--------------------Biblography----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, uniquename=false, uniquelist=false, block=none, hyperref=true, bibencoding=utf8,citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,maxcitenames=5,maxbibnames=99,backend=biber,sortcites,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\let\cite\autocite


\addbibresource{ref_list.bib}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[pdftex,
            bookmarks=true,
            bookmarksnumbered=false,  % true means numbered bookmarks
                                      % appear in the left window
            bookmarksopen=false,      % true means bookmarks within a
                                      % section are open by default
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=webbrown,
            linkcolor=webred,
            urlcolor=webred]{hyperref}

\definecolor{bl}{rgb}{0.0,0.2,0.6}       
\definecolor{webbrown}{rgb}{0.6, 0, 0} % less intense red for cite
\definecolor{webblue}{rgb}{0, 0, 0.5}  % less intense blue
\definecolor{webred}{rgb}{0.5, 0, 0}   % less intense red for figures

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\usepackage{flafter}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep}
\setlist{nolistsep,leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\headheight 65pt

%----------- Other Pages -------------
\pagestyle{fancy}{
\fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{SMB2020_logo}}
       \fancyhead[R]{Insert title\\Paper ID: xx\\}
       %-ACCEPTED FOR PRESENTATION \& REVISED
    \fancyfoot[L]{\textit{\small{ Conference, 9 May}}}
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
}

%----------- First Page -------------

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo}}
\fancyhead[R]{CONFERENCE \\ city\\ Paper ID: xx \\}
    }
%--------------- Begin Document ---------------------


\begin{document}


\title{\vspace{-1.4cm} \large{insert title}}

\author[1,2]{Author 1 \thanks{Corresponding author. Address:  \\ author_1@email}\thanks{Assistant Professor of Economics}}

 \author[2]{Author 2 \thanks{Assistant Professor of Logistics, email}}

\affil[1]{\scriptsize{Affiliation 1}}
\affil[2]{\scriptsize{Affiliation 2}}

\date{}
%----------------------------------------------
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\maketitle
\vspace{-1.5cm}

%--------------------------------- Abstract -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section*{Abstract}
Insert text
%------------------------------ References -------------------------------------
\section*{References}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\newrefcontext[sorting=nty]
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please extend this code do a full minimal self contained document. The code presented has nothing to do with affiliations.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please provide a **complete** [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` so that it is easier for us to reproduce your problem and fix it.

Comment: thank you, I just did